# Android Socket Client Runnable didn't stop

Tags: java, android, android-intent, network-programming

I am using the following code to connect my client to the server. The problem is this doesn't terminate and I am unable to start a new activity after this one.

I think the problem is either I don't close the socket or the thread doesn't terminate.

I start the thread in `onCreate()`

```
cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
cThread.start();
```

And here is my `Runnable`

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8080);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new
                      OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        // where you issue the commands

                        out.println(serverIpAddress);
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error while sending", e);
                }

                connected = false;
            }
            //socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error while connecting", e);
            connected = false;
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is quite useless. Assuming the socket is estabilished, the `while` loop is executed only once because, at the end of the first iteration, you set `connected` to `false`, thus disabling any further cycle. You don't flush your buffered output to ensure it's written, and you **don't even read** from the socket, so I wonder what your custom protocol looks like... At this moment, all your program does is simply writing a string to a server, then exiting. We can't even tell why you are not able to start a new activity, because in the supplied code there is nothing preventing you from doing so.

There are basically two kinds of TCP protocols

1. Request-response based (like HTTP, not suitable for a chat program). The client estabilishes a connection, makes a request, reads the response, makes another request, reads the new response and so on, till the client has finished its job. A graphical client will need 2 threads at least: one for the UI update and the other for network communication.
2. Client and server both send messages at random times. This leverages the full-duplex capability of socket communication, however you'll need at least three threads in a GUI program: one for the UI, one blocked on the socket's input stream, and one for writing. Things get quite messy because you'll likely share streams and have to synchronize by hand.

If this is yet another chat program, I'd suggest not to design your own TCP protocol, and start with a standard technology like [WebSockets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). There are [Java clients](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets) available, and you may test your server simply with a bit of Javascript in your browser, and there are even more choices on the server side ([Socket.IO](http://socket.io) - for a JS solution, [Jetty, Glassfish](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-websocket-chat), ...).

After you get some experience and become acquainted with the job, you may try to design your own custom TCP protocol. By the time, you'll have learned at least the basics of sockets, threads and Android programming.

BTW, you may want to take a look at the [`Service` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for background tasks which don't require user interaction.